# How to ensure custom order of traits upon mixing them in?

Tags: scala, traits

Can I create something to keep the order of traits during their mixing in control?

I mean something like, using parameterized traits or not - it's not mandatory:

```
trait Order

trait ItsOrderIsImportant[Order] { 
//...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can just declare trait to be mixed with other types, like this:

```
trait B

trait A { this: B =>
}
```

With this, trait `A` is only allowed to be mixed in to types with trait `B` mixed in.

Comment: Then it would help to know what your use-case is, in case there's some other way of doing it.